# Regex, Number or Empty

Tags: regex

Can someone show me how to match 4 digits **or** nothing in Regex? I have been using RegexBuddy and so far i have come up with this but the help text is saying '*Or match regular expression number 2 below - the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match*' in regards to the pattern after the pipe.

I would like either of the two to provide a positive match.

```
^\d{4}|$
```

Comment: The regex above is correct. Of course ^ means start of line and $ means end of line, I'm not sure if in your scenario that would be required. But `\d{4}|` indeed means "4 digits or nothing".

Comment: Would that actually match starts with 4 digits or nothing. So 1234a would match

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either 4 digits or nothing:

```
^(?:\d{4}|)$
```

This is closest to what you were trying to do.

I would go for the following for a slightly shorter one:

```
^(?:\d{4})?$
```

---

```
^\d{4}|$
```

That regex means either:

`^\d{4}` OR `$`

The first will match just any string that starts with 4 digits while the second will report a match on *everything* (it matches the end of a string, and since no character is specified, it will match the end of all strings).

When you're using a group, you're getting:

Either `^(?:\d{4})$` or `^(?:)$`  (notice that the 'limits' of the OR operator changed), which is then equivalent to either `^\d{4}$` or `^$`

Comment: might be worth explaining that `^\d{4}|$` would match `1234a` because the $ is not included in the first match

Comment: @BobVale I might also add that `^\d{4}|$` as a whole will match anything because of `$` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is sound. You do need to keep operator precedence in mind though and use either

```
^(\d{4}|)$
```

or

```
^\d{4}$|^$
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if it needs *OR*

```
^(\d{4})?$
```