# Using a regular expression validator to check for 11 digit number or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using the following code to validate a text box against either empty or 11 digit numbers (which are both correct while every other combination of characetrs is incorrect).

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    ID="numbertextboxval" 
    runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="number not correct"
    Display="Static"
    ControlToValidate="numbertextbox"
    ValidationExpression="([0-9]{11} | (^.))"/>
```

I also tried to use:
^(\s*|([0-9]{11}))  instead.

The effect is always the same. Empty works. but 11 digits are identified as INCORRECT.

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: By default, whitespace is significant, so this only matches 11 digits followed by a space. Remove the spacing around `|`.

Comment: the regex is quite simple `\d{11}` or `|` nothing ``.. give `^(\d{11}|)$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex, Number or Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957119/regex-number-or-empty)

Comment: Is zero a valid starting char? If not then you need something like `[1-9]\d{10}`

Comment: If you want to match 11 digits or an empty string try `^(?:[0-9]{11})?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition will consider spaces as valid, while you are looking for empty only. Try the following regular expression:

```
\d{11}|^$
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid your space....RegularExpressionValidator and use RequiredFieldValidator for checking null value ....**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the digits cannot start with zero then use:

```
^([1-9]\d{10})?$
```

If zero is allowed as the first char then refer to the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111720/2191572